# HP Pavilion G4 2118TU drive

Tags: hard-drive, hp-pavilion

everyone. My HP Pavilion G4 bought with suse linux OS, but when I change it to ubuntu, I couldn't find the drive softwave for linux(hp-drive-guard - HP DriveGuard; touch drive.....) would you help me, please?

Comment: I have a suspicion that by "drive" you mean "drivers". Otherwise, please explain what "touch drive" is

Comment: lol，im no good at english:) Maybe I should express it" I need driveGuard and laptop touchpad driver ".I google the drivers but cannot get answer. Would you have some method to solve it? thanks @Sergey

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as : how do I install additional drivers ?

Launch the "Software Sources" app. Go to the "Additional drivers" tab. Here are options to install new drivers.

Did my explanation help ?

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried as your answer, it's just say "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system", maybe the "Additional drivers" cannot identify the drivers.....

Comment: Could you please edit your question, to improve the English ? If you want, also add your question in your original language. Somone will try to translate it.